# Подсчет количества строк, где значение не изменялось

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица:

```
  ID               date             value
----------------------------------------------
"148512" | "2019-07-15 04:35:00" | "1"
"148511" | "2019-07-15 04:30:00" | "-1"
"148509" | "2019-07-15 04:25:00" | "-1"
"148506" | "2019-07-15 04:20:00" | "1"
"148504" | "2019-07-15 04:15:00" | "1"
"148503" | "2019-07-15 04:10:00" | "-1"
"148501" | "2019-07-15 04:05:00" | "-1"
"148499" | "2019-07-15 04:00:00" | "-1"
"148496" | "2019-07-15 03:55:00" | "1"
```

хочу получить выборку данных, где `value` было отрицательным и не изменялось с предыдущей `date`. Что-то вроде этого:

```
date                    sum
---------------------------
"2019-07-15 04:30:00" | "2"
"2019-07-15 04:10:00" | "3"
```

буду благодарен за любые подсказки как это можно сделать.

**UPD** 
Дополнительное условие с проверкой `type`:

```
  ID     type        date             value
----------------------------------------------
"148512" | 1 | "2019-07-15 04:35:00" | "1"
"148511" | 2 | "2019-07-15 04:30:00" | "-1"
"148509" | 2 | "2019-07-15 04:25:00" | "-1"
"148506" | 1 | "2019-07-15 04:20:00" | "1"
"148504" | 1 | "2019-07-15 04:15:00" | "1"
"148503" | 1 | "2019-07-15 04:10:00" | "-1"
"148501" | 1 | "2019-07-15 04:05:00" | "-1"
"148499" | 2 | "2019-07-15 04:00:00" | "-1"
"148496" | 1 | "2019-07-15 03:55:00" | "1"
```

```
date                    sum   type
---------------------------------
"2019-07-15 04:30:00" | "2" |  2
"2019-07-15 04:10:00" | "2" |  1
"2019-07-15 04:00:00" | "1" |  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(dt), MAX(cnt)
FROM ( SELECT dt, 
              CASE WHEN val= 1 THEN @cnt:=0
                   WHEN val=-1 AND @prev= 1 THEN @cnt:=1
                   WHEN val=-1 AND @prev=-1 THEN @cnt:=@cnt+1
              END cnt,
              @gr:=@gr+(val=-1 AND @prev=1) gr,
              @prev:=val prev
       FROM test, 
            ( SELECT @gr:=0, @prev:=1, @cnt:=0 ) vars
       ORDER BY dt DESC
     ) cte
WHERE cnt > 0
GROUP BY gr
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно! спасибо!
А можете еще подсказать как добиться этого же результата, если  в таблице присутствует еще одно дополнительное поле `type`, и нужно получить тоже самое но с учетом его значения ?

Comment: @Sprait Внесите корректировки в подзапрос, чтобы формировать нужный критерий нумерации групп.

Comment: Спасиба вам еще раз! методом проб и ошибок удалось получить желаемое.